# Docker ignore target directories created by mave using .dockerignore file

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile, dockerignore

I am building maven project using maven docker image. Maven project is very big like more than 300mb source code. So when I run docker build it needs to send all build context[source code] to Docker daemon. The issue is suppose if I have already build my maven project then source code size becomes more than 5gb including all the target directories.

So in .dockerignore I need to ignore all the /target/ directories.

I tried this but its not working

```
.git
**/target/*.*
```

Comment: Try `target/*` . You can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25491051/1563297

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above seemed to work for me (docker version 20.10.5).  In the end, the following worked out OK:

.dockerignore:

```
**/target/
```

Here is an excerpt from the [.dockerignore documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file):

> Beyond Go’s filepath.Match rules, Docker also supports a special
> wildcard string ** that matches any number of directories (including
> zero). For example, **/*.go will exclude all files that end with .go
> that are found in all directories, including the root of the build
> context.

Answer (score 1):

It should be same as we do it in `.gitignore`, so to ignore target folder just use `target/`.